# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, connection-string, invalidoperationexception

I'm using an asp.net web application with a MySql DB, with the following connetcion string the web.config:

```
<add name="techConnectionString" connectionString="server=vm-tmysql01;User Id=user;database=tech;password=pass" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

And this is the code I'm using the get the connection string from the web.config:

```
System.configuration.configurationmanaget.connectionstrings["techConnectionString"].connectionstring;
```

For some reason I get the error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. An unhandled
>   exception was generated during the execution of the current web
>   request. Information regarding the origin and location of the
>   exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

And the stack trace is:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand() +6316916
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6296606
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +300
```

I'm able to connect to the DB via the Data Sources in Visual Studio and took the ConnectionString from there.
I really need some help with it, is there any problem with my connection string?

Comment: try changing to System.configuration.configurationmanagement.connectionstrings["techConnectionString"].connectionstring;

Comment: Also, make sure that the <add name is in the corrent node of the web.config.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/403a6210-5c8d-4c6c-abda-7d8e138facee/the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Answer (score 3):

The problem wasn't with the connetion string, it was with the c# code trying to reach it from the web.config file.

i was trying to use:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["techConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

But i needed to use:

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["techConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Ah. Noone caught that! You should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

change connection string as

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="techConnectionString" connectionString="SERVER=vm-tmysql01; DATABASE=tech; UID=user; 
PASSWORD=pass" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

and you can get connection using `System.Configuration` ( you need to add reference to `System.Configuration`)

```
var constring =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["techConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```